# Angular filter on a single string array

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material

I am looking at the example of angular material filter

however I edited so it only display one column in my example here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w6nxqd

the filter do not work when i pass the data source as a string[] for some reason

is this not meant to work with string [] and I must have a define class ?

Comment: This question would be greatly improved if you shared a stackblitz which shows the changes you've made which don't work.  The stackblitz you shared is a fully working filter based material table example. Can you modify this example with your changes and reshare?  This will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work since your data set is an array of strings, not an array of objects.  Add a filter predicate to tell the MatTableDataSource how to filter:

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => data.indexOf(filter) != -1;
```